# Problema con relaciones en Base de datos

Tags: diagrama-er

Hace tiempo tuve que entregar un trabajo donde debía crear una un esquerma relacional , también un diagrama workbench entre las distintas tablas, (importando las relacione en FK).

Realicé el ejercicio y el profesor me ha dado una serie de fallos a corregir,(Malas cardinalidades sobre todo) pero no entiendo bien la lógica detrás de ellos, ni cuál sería la respuesta correcta.

---

El enunciado pide una serie de características en las ventas debemos reflejar la fecha de la venta, el cliente que compra, los artículos que se incluyen y el vendedor que realiza la operación.
Mi esquema fue el siguiente

[image: 1]

Por lo visto, **tengo mal** las cardinalidades, por ejemplo entre Ventas y Productos o entre Vendedores y Ventas, no se bien la razón.

Fallos en el Esquema Relacional:

Por lo visto, la siguiente relación que es entre Venta y Vendedores no está bien resuelta. Y faltan FK en las relaciones 1:N

Trabajos(idTrabajo, idVentafk, idVendedorFK)

Clientes(idCliente, dniCliente, nombreCliente, apellidosCliente, poblacionCLiente,correoElectronicoCliente, telefonoCliente, provinciaCliente, codigoPostalCliente)

Productos(idProducto, precioVentaProducto, codigoProducto,cantidadAlmacenProducto, descripcionProducto, medidasProducto,precioCompraProducto, ivaAplicableProducto, descuentoProducto)

Ventas(idVenta, fechaVenta, idClienteFK1, idProductoFK2, idVendedorFK3)

---

Segundo Ejercicio

Se supone que los trabajadores se encargarán de las distintas motos las cuales pueden ser trabajadas
entre varios.

Esquema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, tengo mal la relación entre Facturas y Trabajadores

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y le preguntaste a tu profesor? el va a saber mucho mejor que nosotros, no....

Answer (score 0):

Mi consejo es que pongas en palabras lo que dice tu esquema. Respecto a la relación entre vendedores y ventas:

- **Un vendedor genera varias ventas**: parece correcto, si yo soy vendedor, lo lógico es que haga varias ventas en toda mi vida
- **Una venta es generada por varios vendedores**: ¿cómorrrrrr? Excepto en negocios muy raros donde concurran varios vendedores para llevar a cabo una venta, esto es extremadamente atípico. Entiendo que el *espiritu* del ejercicio es modelizar algo más o menos "normal", por lo que aquí debería ser *"Una venta es generada por un sólo vendedor"**: esto te dará la pista de que la relación es 1:N, no M:N como tú has puesto

Con los clientes, lo mismo:

- **Un cliente genera varias ventas**: pues parece correcto
- **Una venta es generada por varios clientes**: Error de nuevo. Que yo sepa, una venta la generará un único cliente, nuevamente es lo normal.

En el caso de las facturas y los trabajadores, lo mismo, pronuncia con palabras tu propio esquema y me dices si "suena" normal:

- Una factura es emitida por varios trabajadores
- Un trabajador sólo puede emitir una factura

Tal y como lo has modelado, parece un negocio bastante ruinoso. Mira a ver.